# Unexpected space below label tag

Tags: html, css, spacing

I've stripped the example to the minimum, and the question is: where does the space between the lower side of the square and the outer `div` come from? How can I get rid of it, without changing the HTML tree?

```css
.choice-picker {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.choice-picker > input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-left: -9999px;
}

.choice-picker > input + label > * {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="choice-picker">
  <input type="radio" id="choice1" name="choices" checked="checked">
  <label for="choice1">
    <div style="width: 3em; height: 3em; background-color: black;"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-left: -9999px;` Why?

Comment: To send the radio button away. Probably `visibility: hidden;` will do the same. But this doesn't seem what's causing the spacing behavior I observe...

Comment: vertical-align:top to the inline-block element